# execute cql shell file or command in JAVA

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax

I need to use the cqlsh copy to command in my java application. (`copy keyspace.table (column1, column2) to 'path';`)

So, is there a way to execute a cqlsh file with that command or just execute the command in the java code?

Thanks!

Comment: The answer is "most probably, yes".

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Because `COPY` is `cqlsh` command, not CQL expression, then only way is to launch `cqlsh` from the Java code via `-e` command line switch, for example, you can use [Apache Commons Exec library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-exec/), but you'll need to have `cqlsh` installed on the machine where your Java program runs.

P.S. `COPY` not always the best way - DataStax has [DSBulk utility](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dsbulk/doc/index.html) that is heavily optimized for performant data loading and unloading.